# Find $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times r}$, $B \in \mathbb{R}^{r \times n}$, with $m > n \geq r$, such that $(A \cdot B)^+$ can be trivially computed

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

Is it possible to define matrices $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times r}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{r \times n}$, with $m > n \geq r$, so that the [pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) of their product, $(A \cdot B)^+$, can be computed easily (e.g. by matrix multiplications, transpositions)?

I understand that the [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) could be used for that, by defining $A=U \cdot \Sigma$ and $B=V^T$, which would lead to $(A \cdot B)^+ = V \Sigma^+ U^T$.

However, I would like to avoid computations with large matrices from $\mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ (like $U$) due to memory restrictions.

<s>Update: given the nature of my problem, $A$ should be full column rank (like $(A\cdot B)^+$) and $B$ should be full row rank, so I cannot define $A$ to be diagonal-like.</s>

Update 1: given the nature of my problem, $A$ and $B$ should be "dense", in the sense that most of their elements are non-zero.

Update 2: it would also be Ok if instead of having a multiplication of two matrices, we had a series of simple operations on N matrices, as long as the result is $m \times n$ and the dimentionality of the matrices involved is at most $m\times n$

Comment: If you take $A$ already of the form $\Sigma$, then $U$ is an identity matrix.

Comment: @MeesdeVries I don't understand, can you please elaborate?

Comment: $\Sigma$ is a diagonal-like matrix. If you take $A$ to be a diagonal-like matrix, then you get to work with $A = I \times A$, which avoids the problem that you mention.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand. You made me realize that I need $A$ and $B$ to be full rank. I will update the question.

Comment: A diagonal-like matrix has the largest rank that a matrix of its particular dimensions allows (namely, its rank is the minimum of its two dimensions, which is easily seen to be optimal).

Comment: You are right, rank is indeed not the proper way to define the requirement I have. What I actually want is a "dense" matrix, in the sense that most of its elements are non-zero. I don't know how to express it better.